# ReportItems Sums by Grouping

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2012, ssrs-tablix

I have a data like this
[Original Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/boL3y.png)

and i intend to create the output like this
[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tuZg3.png)

I have made the SSRS with Expression for debit like this

`=IIF(SUM(Fields!Amount.Value)>0,SUM(Fields!Amount.Value),0)`

and on credit like this

`=IIF(SUM(Fields!Amount.Value)<0,SUM(Fields!Amount.Value),0)`

The problem i have was i don't know how to total the report items on debit and credit column.
I tried this expression for totaling the debit and credit

`=SUM(ReportItems!DebitColumn.Value)`
`=SUM(ReportItems!CreditColumn.Value)`

the result is error. Is there an expression or something to total those debet and credit column per group A ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do some of this work in SQL, this will make the report simple.

I started by recreating your sample data and aggregating as follows...

```
DECLARE @t TABLE (Group1 char(1), Group2 int, Amount float)
INSERT INTO @t VALUES
('A', 1, 1000),('A', 1, -500),('A', 1, -250),('A', 1, -500),
('A', 1, 100),('A', 2, 200),('A', 2, -500),('A', 2, -200),
('A', 2, 400),('A', 2, 200),('A', 3, -50),('A', 3, 0)

SELECT Group1, Group2, SUM(Amount) AS Amount
FROM @t
    GROUP BY Group1, Group2
```

Then in the report I added a matrix with row groups from `Group1` and `Group2`.

I added a column grouping using the following expression.

```
=IIF(Fields!Amount.Value >0, "Debit", "Credit")
```

I changed the column group sorting to use the same expression with order `Z to A`

Finally, I also set the column header expression to the same expression.

[image]

I then added a total to the Group1 row group.

The final output looks like this.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Firstly amend your dataset using the following query:

```
SELECT        [Group 1], [Group 2], SUM(Amount) AS Amount
FROM            Table_3
GROUP BY [Group 1], [Group 2]
```

Then add a calculated field labelled as "text" into your dataset using the following expression:

```
=IIF(Fields!Amount.Value > 0 , "Debit","Credit")
```

Next create a matrix whereby Group 1 and Group 2 are adjacent row groups and text field is your column group. Drag the amount field into the column group, this field does not require an aggregate as it is already aggregated by your SQL query. The title label for this column group will be the text field.